# MvxAutoCompleteTextView binding with 2 Properties

Tags: android, xamarin, binding, mvvmcross

I'm currently trying to make a Xamarin.Android App using MvvmCross.

This is what I am trying to achieve:

[image: Multiline autocomplete]

This is the axml that's behind it:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
    <MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.Views.MvxAutoCompleteTextView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:hint="Klant naam"
       local:MvxBind="Text Klant.Naam; ItemsSource KlantNamen; PartialText CurrentKlantHint; SelectedObject SelectedKlant" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

I want to use a list containing a Name and a number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to supply MvxAutoCompleteTextView with an Item Template, in order to show something custom in the suggestions.

```
<MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.Views.MvxAutoCompleteTextView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:hint="Klant naam"
       local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/my_template"
       local:MvxBind="Text Klant.Naam; ItemsSource KlantNamen; PartialText CurrentKlantHint; SelectedObject SelectedKlant" />
```

Inside of `my_template` you would define your own layout for each of the suggested items. Where you bind the views inside of that template to the properties of the ViewModels in your `KlantNamen` collection.

This could look something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
    android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
    android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
    android:paddingRight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingRight"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
        local:MvxBind="Text Name" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
        local:MvxBind="Text Price" />
</LinearLayout>
```